# AutoFill-LoginName-TextBox-MVC 3 -ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using windows authentication. I have login name availble in a string, got that from current logged in user.

I am using MVC3 with Razor. I need to autopopulate the textbox with the current logged in username and should be readonly. How can I bind these in MVC 3 ASp.NET. Any directions, Please?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass login name to view in viewbag:

In your controller code:

```
 ViewBag.UserName = username;
```

And use it in your view like this:

```
 <input type="text" name="UserName" value="@ViewBag.UserName" readonly="readonly">
```